# Why model.evaluate_generator gives 0 loss and accuracy tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

Hi I have successfully trained the binary classification model for predicting male(0) or female(1). As you can see below after my training is completed I did evaluation which resulted zero loss and zero accuracy with no errors or warnings. Though my model can make good amount "TRUE" predictions for male(0) or female(1) from test_data set. Can anyone please guide me how to fix evaluate or evaluate_generator so that it shows loss and accuracy on test_data? It would be really helpful for me to learn new concepts if I can get some advice Thanks

```
 train_data = imgdatagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train,x_col="Filepath",directory="/content/crop_part1/",y_col="Gender",class_mode="binary",target_size=(48,48),subset='training')
    Found 6258 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.

val_data = imgdatagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train,x_col="Filepath",directory="/content/crop_part1/",y_col="Gender",class_mode="binary",target_size=(48,48),subset="validation")
Found 1564 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.

testimgdatagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_data = testimgdatagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test,x_col="Filepath",directory="/content/crop_part1/",y_col="",class_mode=None,target_size=(48,48))
Found 1956 validated image filenames.
model = []

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
#sigmoid activation function
##Here we can also use softmax as Activation function
##In the scenario of using softmax there will be 2 neurons in the output layer
##Such as 
##model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax',name="Dense_layer_2"))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit_generator(train_data,validation_data=val_data,epochs=50)##poting only last 5 epochs to decrease the length of content
Epoch 45/50
196/196 [==============================] - 7s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0916 - accuracy: 0.9638 - val_loss: 1.1861 - val_accuracy: 0.8024
Epoch 46/50
196/196 [==============================] - 7s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0966 - accuracy: 0.9621 - val_loss: 0.9765 - val_accuracy: 0.8005
Epoch 47/50
196/196 [==============================] - 7s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0574 - accuracy: 0.9767 - val_loss: 0.9846 - val_accuracy: 0.8095
Epoch 48/50
196/196 [==============================] - 7s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0593 - accuracy: 0.9795 - val_loss: 0.8503 - val_accuracy: 0.8133
Epoch 49/50
 43/196 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.0770 - accuracy: 0.9640
model.evaluate(test_data)
62/62 [==============================] - 2s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
[0.0, 0.0]
```